# How to overlay pages in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to create a code for overlay pages in Xamarin.
The goal is realize something like a picker in android.

I mean, have your mainpage in background and in overlay the second page
This is the effect I want:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogosn.png)

Is there a way for do this?

Comment: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: It's a listview on a PopupPage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to display a simple message or control, I'd suggest [Xamarin's popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup) from the community toolkit. It the simplest solution.

However, if you are truly looking to have a "full page" overlaid, I'd suggest you look into [Xamarin's modal pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal). This would keep your underlying page navigational stack and just add a page atop, to be popped off stack at dismissal.